# Authorize.Net sandbox not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, authorize.net

controller: PaymentController.php

```
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

public function check()
{
    return view('payment.payment');
}

public function chargeCreditCard(Request $request)
{
    // Common setup for API credentials
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(config('services.authorize.login'));
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(config('services.authorize.key'));
    $refId = 'ref'.time();
    // Create the payment data for a credit card
    $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
    $creditCard->setCardNumber($request->cnumber);
    // $creditCard->setExpirationDate( "2038-12");
    $expiry = $request->card_expiry_year . '-' . $request->card_expiry_month;
    $creditCard->setExpirationDate($expiry);
    $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);
    // Create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($request->camount);
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId( $refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
    if ($response != null)
    {
        $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
        if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()=="1"))
        {
            echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
            echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

view: Payment/Payment.blade.php

```
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Authorize Payment Integration</h1>
        <form class="" action="{{ url('/checkout') }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <h3>Credit Card Information</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cnumber">Card Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnumber" name="cnumber" placeholder="Enter Card Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="card-expiry-month">Expiration Month</label>
                <select name="card_expiry_month" class="form-control" required="required">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="card-expiry-year">Expiration Year</label>
            <select name="card_expiry_year" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                <option value="2029">2029</option>
            </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ccode">Card Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ccode" name="ccode" placeholder="Enter Card Code">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="camount">Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="camount" name="camount" placeholder="Enter Amount" >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/checkout', 'PaymentController@check');
Route::post('/checkout', 'PaymentController@chargeCreditCard');
```

In this code I had integrate Authorize.Net Payment gateway API. Now, The problem is when I click on submit then nothing happen. If I am not wrong then the problem rises from the `form action=""` that's why it not go to `checkout`. So, How can I fix this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: is redirecting working? redirecting to the `/` URL

Comment: No, @DhavalPurohit

Comment: Then is it going to the controller function ?

Comment: No, @DhavalPurohit its not

Comment: Kindly check the output in inspect element is the generated URL is valid? @omkara